# tangent for 3-dimensional function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

How can I calculate a tangent at a point $(x_0, y_0)$ in the direction $(r_1, r_2)$ for a $3-$dimensional function $f(x,y)$?

I thought:
\begin{equation*}
T: (x_0, y_0, f(x_0,y_0)) + k \cdot (r_1, r_2, grad (r_1, r_2)). 
\end{equation*}
Is this Correct?

Do I have to normalise $grad (r_1,r_2)$?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a two-variable function $f(x,y)$ has, in principle, an infinite number of derivatives (and hence, an infinite number of tangents) at any point $(x_0,y_0)$. Given a two-dimensional vector $\overrightarrow{\mu}$ on the $(x,y)$-plane, you can obtain the corresponding directional derivative of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ in the direction of $\overrightarrow{\mu}$ with the aid of the scalar product $\overrightarrow{\nabla}f(x_0,y_0) \cdot \overrightarrow{\mu}$, where $\overrightarrow{\nabla}f(x_0,y_0)$ is the gradient of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$, i.e. the vector of partial derivatives. In this case, $\overrightarrow{\mu}$ should be a unitary vector.

Once you have the directional derivative, you have the slope of the tangent in the direction of $\overrightarrow{\mu}$. Then you can construct the tangent line by making this line pass through the point $(x_0, y_0, f(x_0,y_0))$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)$ is not a 3D function, it is a 2D surface if you graph it as a height map, that's all.

You should not normalize the gradient.

The end result should look something like this:

$$f(x,y)\rightarrow f(x_o,y_o)+(x-x_o)f_x(x_o,y_o)+(y-y_0)f_y(x_o,y_o)+\text{higher order terms}$$

higher order terms go on like a taylor series:

$$\frac12 \bigg((x-x_o)^2f_{xx}(x_o,y_o)+(y-y_0)^2f_{yy}(x_o,y_o))+2(x-x_o)(y-y_0) f _{xy} (x_o,y_o)\bigg) $$